# Using Linq in MVVM Cross Bind Statements

Tags: c#, android, linq, mvvmcross

In MVVM Cross binding statements can I use a linq expression?

For example; in my ItemTemplate `item_places.axml`:

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/placesVideo"
    local:MvxBind="VideoUri myPlace.videos.FirstOrDefault().url" />

// Models
public class MyPlace
{
    public List<Video> videos { get; set; }
}

public class Video
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No thats not possible (as far as I know). You could achive this by adding another property to your Model:

```
public class MyPlace
{
    public List<Video> videos { get; set; }

    public Video MyFirstVideo
    {
        get
        {
            return videos.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Then your binding looks as following:

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/placesVideo"
    local:MvxBind="VideoUri myPlace.MyFirstVideo.url" />
```

But be carefully: You don't have a `PropertyChanged` here. So when you update your Video-List, nothing is changing in your view!